# Simple doorbell delay (add-on)

Tags: analog, dc, timer, delay

We have a new office doorbell with a pushbutton that rings a buzzer for as long as the button is held down (i.e. a simple circuit that is closed by the button). The buzzer sound is really "angry", and people tend to either:

- hold the button down for long
- ring again before someone has had a chance to open the door

.. which is driving me mad.

Is there a simple component to add inline to introduce a X second delay before the buzzer can be rung again? i.e. something that detects when a circuit is closed, and prevents it from being closed again for a configurable delay.

The accuracy of the delay length is not too important: e.g a variation of 5-15 seconds is fine.

Comment: Google "monostable"

Comment: There isn't a single component I can think of to do this. The simplest arrangement I can think of would involve an IC, transistor and ten or so passive components so you'd need some basic electronics experience to build it, I gather you're just after a simple end solution? Unless you're planning electronics as a new hobby and spend some time on it you might be best to find a local EE student / hobbyist to come up with something at a reasonable cost or hire a professional if cost is not so much of an issue.

Comment: Or, get a friendlier sounding doorbell. Here, a unit with nice, real mechanical chimes costs about $25.